# Including source files in Cordova project from outside the project's directory hierarchy

Tags: javascript, cordova, packaging

**tl;dr:** I want to include some JavaScript files from another project in another directory into a Cordova project, without (manually) copying those files into my Cordova project directory tree. How?

---

I am editing an existing Cordova project that makes use of some JavaScript source files originally written for a large web application project.
Currently, I am adding these source files by copying them to a subdirectory of the Cordova project, and by adding a `<script>` tag with the relative path to an `index.html` file in the Cordova project. This causes the JavaScript files to integrated in the deployed app, apparently by virtue of Cordova's (or Ionic's?) magic.

Now, it would be preferrable for me to avoid copying the JavaScript files to my Cordova project directory. Instead, I would like to directly link to the files in their original location rather than copying them (so updates from the web application get automatically applied to the Cordova project, as well).

As both the Cordova project and the large web application reside in the same VCS repository, the relative path to the files will always be the same - for the sake of an example, like this:

```
|-repository/
  |-web/
  | |-src/
  |   |-myCode.js
  |-cordova
    |-src
      |-index.html
      |-helpers
        |-myCode.js // copy of /repository/web/src/myCode.js
```

Therefore, I have tried setting the relative path in the aforementioned `index.html` file - but unfortunately, Cordova seems to take over that file verbatim, and thus, the resulting URL will not exist (prompting a 404 error in the console, and causing the code from the file to be unavailable).

**How can I have Cordova include and reference files from outside the directory hierarchy of a Cordova project?**

Is there maybe at least a way to have Ionic or Cordova automatically copy the files into the Cordova project directory upon building the app?